# nodejs - aws lambda random timeout when trying to access S3.getBucketLocation

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda

For the following code, I was asked to check, which runs on `AWS Lambda` and performs the simple task of uploading files to `S3`, timesout randomly when run manually from the `aws console`,
but at the same time when run on a schedule, will always timeout at the first attempt and then run successfully the second time
(it is run immediately after failing the first time).
The code always seems to hang after calling `s3.getBucketLocation`, never reaching the `getBucketLocation`'s callback(on the first attempt!).

All `VPC's` and `NAT` are set-up correctly, such that, when I remove `s3.getBucketLocation` from the code and call `s3Upload.upload(params, cb);` 
directly, the code runs without timeouts.

I would really like to understand why the first function fails alternatively when trying to retrieve the buckets region from `AWS`.

```
"use strict";

var urlHelper = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

var exp = {};

function saveToFile(path, content, cb) {
    fs.writeFile(path, content, cb);
}

function saveToS3(bucket, key, content, cb) {
  var s3 = new AWS.S3({apiVersion: '2006-03-01'});
  var params = {
    Bucket: bucket
  };
  s3.getBucketLocation(params, function(err, data) {
    console.log('THIS IS NOT REACHED');
    if (err) {
      return cb(err);
    }
    var s3Upload = new AWS.S3({
      apiVersion: '2006-03-01',
      region: data.LocationConstraint
    });
    var params = {
      Bucket: bucket,
      Key: key,
      Body: content,
      ACL: 'public-read',
      ContentType: 'text/xml',
      CacheControl: 'max-age=60'
    };
    s3Upload.upload(params, cb);
  });
}

exp.upload = function(path, content, cb) {
  var url = urlHelper.parse(path);
  switch(url.protocol) {
  case 'file:':
  case null:
    saveToFile(path, content, cb);
    break;
  case 's3:':
    saveToS3(url.host, url.pathname.substring(1), content, cb);
    break;
  default:
    console.log('No matching protocol found for upload!');
    cb(null, null);
  }
};

module.exports = exp;
```

Comment: *The code always seems to hang after calling s3.getBucketLocation, never reaching it's callback.*  Never reaching which callback?  You aren't writing any imtermediate log messages in the getBucketLocation callback, so I'm not sure how you can tell where it's timing out.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I have edited my question as to clear your doubts. When I say _never reaching it's callback_ I'm referring to the **getBucketLocation**, which I thought was clear, as I don't mention any other function in that sentence, and I know it hangs at that point because before asking people to spend their time trying to help me, I have tested the code myself to see where it was failing (by adding a log as I have now for you)

Comment: How long are you allowing the function to run before timeout, when invoked?  If you increase that time enough, you *should* find that the callback eventually fires, potentially with a useful error.

Comment: We had initially set it to 10secs. I then tried to up it to 30secs and still timedout without an error message. Because Lambda charges per time run, I didn't really want to set the time to its max. Also it didn't really make sense that such a simple request should take more than 30 secs to execute.
I will try and up the timeout limit to the max time allowed by lambda and see what happens.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that you leave it high, but do turn it up temporarily and see what happens.  Also, add a log statement on a new line immediately before calling `s3.getBucketLocation()`, to verify that an unusual amount of time does not elapse *before* that function is actually called.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, it seems that setting the timeout a little higher has thus far resolved the issue. What remains to be solved is why it takes so long to establish a connection and retrieve data from S3.

Comment: How long does it actually take, and how much time is before vs. after the log entry I suggested, above?  I am inclined to think the issue is not really with the S3 request, but something to do with initialization of your environment. Where is the AWS SDK getting your credentials for accessing S3?

Comment: It varies! I had it set at 10secs initially. After the change it sometimes takes 11 secs, 17sec or even 23 secs. All credentials are stored in a config file which is zipped along with all the other necessary code and uploaded to Lambda. It only takes long when it needs to download a file from S3. If I remove the download method it takes around 2 or 3 secs at most.